# how to change the target <a> with a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, hyperlink

So I am using jQuery to change the content of
`<a href="#" id="aX">` to the content of
`<a href="#qX">` 
when clicking on the latter.

I got that working, however I want this to work with each link, so that `#q1` only affects the content of `#a1`, and `#q2` only affects `#a2`.
I tried to pass this with a variable, however it's not working.
What am I doing wrong?

```
var echoPick;

$('#q1 a').click(echoAnswer, function () {
    pickID = '#a1';
});

$('#q2 a').click(echoAnswer, function () {
    pickID = '#a2';
});

var pickID;

function echoAnswer() {
    var yourPick = $(this);
    echoPick = yourPick.text();
    $(pickID).text(echoPick);
}
```

Comment: How many links are there? Are you asking for an abstracted function that handles them all?

Comment: in my project I have 10 links, so yes that would be sweet :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of repeating the same code over and over again for each unique ID, try this:

HTML:
`<a href="#" id="aX">` and `<a href="#qX">`

JS:

```
// Select for all links that start with "#q(...)"
$("a[href^='#q']").click(function(e) {

    // Prevent default
    e.preventDefault();

    // Define some variables
    var x = $(this).attr("href").substr(2),
        content = $(this).text();

    // Select the correct element to replace text
    $("#a" + x).text(content);
});
```

[Edit]: For the sake of completeness - should the content of the link contain HTML tags and you would like to clone them over, use `.html()` instead of `.text()` ;)

See fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/c69P6/

Comment: Really neat code @Terry, this was really what I was after, felt hard to explain in a question though :)

Comment: I suggest you add e.preventDefault (see my suggestion) to stop the link from doing anything else

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for the suggestion :) I have just added a line for that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/H6j6g/1/

```
$("a[id^=q]").click(function(){
    $("#a" + this.id.substring(1)).text($(this).text());
})
```

`$("a[id^=q]")` Will select all links with IDs starting with the letter "q". Then it finds the element with an id with the same number but instead starts with the letter "a" and replaces that link's text with the text of the link that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#q1 a').click(function () {
    $('#a1').text($(this).text());
});
$('#q2 a').click(echoAnswer, function () {
    $('#a2').text($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Sounds to me like the OP wants abstraction. Is that what this is?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not care how many links

Also the e.preventDefault() stops the link from going anywhere

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Gab2P/)

```
$("a").on("click",function(e) {
  var href = this.href.split("#")[1];

  if (href.indexOf("q") == 0 ) {
    var id = href.replace("q","a");
    $("#"+id).text($(this).text())
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```